# Remove an element from an explode() array

Tags: php

I have a bit of a difficult one for you today. I'm trying to set up an inventory system of sorts (via mysqli and a database).

I am storing items - based off of their id,  in a string. (I.E. "1,0,2,1,0").
In order to read the inventory, I am using the 'explode' function.

I need to find a way to 'remove' an item from the inventory.

For example, let's say the inventory is set to "1,2,3,4,5" and I want to remove item 3.

This would leave the inventory set to "1,2,4,5".

Is there any way to do this? The only information I have that is related to the item's location in the string is it's place in the array, made by the explode function.

Comment: _I am storing items - based off of their id, in a string. (I.E. "1,0,2,1,0")_ <<< don't do this

Comment: Any suggestions for alternative methods?

Comment: You have to do array_search() to get the key, and then unset that key before imploding again..... this really is a bad approach.... normalising your database is much better

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Will give it a shot and see if it works out.

Comment: You ask why it's bad to store the values as a single comma delimited value? Because it results in questions like the very one you posted.  If they were stored as separate rows in a related table, it'd be a simple query to add/edit/remove items

Answer (score 1):

While the trivial solution has been given by @MarkBaker in comments (use `array_search` to find the key, then `unset` the key), I will be showing you how to first transform the data into something usable.

```
$items = explode(",",$inventory); // this is presumably what you have so far
$clean_inventory = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
    if( !isset($clean_inventory[$item])) $clean_inventory[$item] = 0;
    $clean_inventory[$item]++;
}

// now delete the item you want
unset($clean_inventory[$item_to_delete]);
// or, if you only want to remove one item,
// $clean_inventory[$item_to_delete]--;

// re-save in the "ugly" format...
$saved = array();
foreach($clean_inventory as $item=>$quantity) {
    $saved = array_merge($saved,array_fill(0,$quantity,$item));
}
$saved = implode(",",$saved);
```

As you can see from the amount of code needed, this is a hint that your data structure is bad, and you should feel bad :p It would be much better to store "item / quantity" pairs in the database in the first place.

Comment: This is a correct way of handling the issue at hand. Although the system I'm using is just for testing purposes, I can now DEFINITELY see the advantages of storing the items & quantities per-user in a separate table. Thank you for your assistance, Niet! I will mark this as an answer ASAP.